# how to upload multiple images properly

Tags: django

I have a simple model which has four different fileFields for uploading different files and images.
this is my models:

```
class DocumentInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    certificate = models.FileField(upload_to="documents", null=True)
    id_card = models.FileField(upload_to="documents", null=True)
    service_certificate = models.FileField(upload_to="documents", null=True)
    educational_certificate = models.FileField(upload_to="documents", null=True)
```

users need to simply upload some images in four individual fields so, I created a simple form and passed it to views like this:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentInfo
        fields = ['certificate','id_card','service_certificate','educational_certificate']
```

views.py:

```
def document_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('document')
        if 'delete' in request.GET:
            return delete_item(DocumentInfo, request.GET['id'])
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    documents = DocumentInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'documents': documents,
    }
    return render(request, 'reg/documents.html', context)
```

it works just fine at first but I cant reupload anything! the uploaded image neither gets saved the second time around nor deleted. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: first,Does your document have a foreignkey to the User model.from what i see this line `documents = DocumentInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)` does nothing because there is no foreignkey or did you forget to show it in your model?

Comment: yes I forgot to add that. but the problem is when the user reuploads a file, a new object will be created. it wont replace the previous.

Answer (score 0):

try this.
views.py

```
def document_info(request):
    documents = DocumentInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-pk')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if documents:
            form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=documents[0])
        else:
            form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            

        if form.is_valid():
            if not documents:
                form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('document')
  
    else:
        if documents:#if the user already has a document.
            form = DocumentForm(instance=documents[0])
        else:
            form = DocumentForm()

    

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'documents': documents,
    }
    return render(request, 'reg/documents.html', context)
```

Comment: it gives me this: list index out of range

Comment: @sam join this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239066/index-out-of-range and we will discuss it.

Comment: @sam i updated my answer.my first answer i assumed that the user already has a document ,but the one that i updated i check whether the user has a document or not.`list index out of range` means that `documents has no data in it so it is empty that why you got that exception`